# How to remove element From Linked Hash Set in java?

Tags: java, linkedhashset

I want to  know Different ways to remove element from Linked Hash Set. I tried following code

```
LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  lhs.add(String.valueOf(i));
Iterator<String>  it=lhs.iterator();
System.out.println("removed?=="+lhs.remove("1"));
while(it.hasNext()) 
{
    System.out.println("lhs"+it.next());
}
```

i got following  output

```
removed?==true
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at preac.chapter1.Start.main(Start.java:321)
```

What i miss? thanks in advance.

P.S  I have also tried iterator.remove() method but got  Illegal State Exception

**EDIT**

I just came to know i have  to use iterator remove  method. then what it is  use of Link Hash Set remove method ?  In  which cases we  should use  this  method?

Comment: use iterator to remove.

Comment: possibly your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection

Comment: @Batty   i tried but  got illegalStateException  error. Could post sample code?

Comment: @saurabh..check Masud's code

Comment: Do the remove() before you start the iterator() and you wont have a problem..

Answer (score 7):

Try to remove element using `Iterator.remove` like below,

```
LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   lhs.add(String.valueOf(i));
}  

Iterator<String>  it=lhs.iterator();
  //  System.out.println("removed?=="+lhs.remove("1"));
 while(it.hasNext()) {
   String value=it.next();
   if("1".equals(value)){
      it.remove();
   }
   else{
      System.out.println("lhs  "+value);// Print the other value except 1
    }
 }
System.out.println(lhs);// After remove see the result here.
```

Comment: it will delete all records in linked HashSet. After your   while  loop i again called   while to print data.but it prints  nothing.I think it is deleting  all data. I want to  delete  only specific  record.

Comment: @saurabh, It will delete only "1", I have tested it.

Comment: your correct..your sysout works . but my    while(it.hasNext()) 
     {
      System.out.println("lhs"+it.next());
     }  is not  executing. I have put these code below sysout.Do you why these happening?

Comment: You should call `it.next()` only once. That has been called before `if` of `while` loop.

Comment: how to iterate the list again with  Iterator?  i  create  new iterator  and assign list to  it and when i try to execute while(newIterator.lhs)  got  an error  no such element Exception.

Comment: while expect the `boolean` value of `it.hasNext()`. `while(newIterator.lhs)`  is not correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41703/discussion-between-saurabh-and-masud)

Answer (score 2):

You get the exception because the iterator realizes that you called `remove` after creating the iterator (using an internal modification counter).

Let's assume `add` and `remove` increment the modification counter by 1.
When the iterator is created, it sees a modification counter of 10.
However, when the iterator is first accessed, the modification counter is 11, due to the call to `remove`, hence the exception.

Switch the statements and it should be fine:

```
...
System.out.println("removed?=="+lhs.remove("1"));
Iterator<String>  it=lhs.iterator();
...
```